# Java - JAIN SIP INVITE does not return response

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

```
public void call(Response response) {
    try {
        cseq++;

        current_process = cseq + " INVITE";
        ArrayList viaHeaders = new ArrayList();
        ViaHeader viaHeader = this.headerFactory.createViaHeader(this.ip,
                5060, "udp", null);
        viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
        // The "Max-Forwards" header.
        MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = this.headerFactory
                .createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
        // The "Call-Id" header.
        CallIdHeader callIdHeader = this.sipProvider.getNewCallId();
        // The "CSeq" header.
        CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = this.headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(cseq,
                "INVITE");

        Address fromAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:"
                + username + '@' + server);

        Address toAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:"+this.toPrefix+this.toNumber+'@'+this.toUri);

        FromHeader fromHeader = this.headerFactory.createFromHeader(
                fromAddress, String.valueOf(this.tag));
        // The "To" header.
        ToHeader toHeader = this.headerFactory.createToHeader(toAddress,
                null);

        ContentLengthHeader contentLength = this.headerFactory.createContentLengthHeader(300);
        ContentTypeHeader contentType = this.headerFactory.createContentTypeHeader("application", "sdp");

        String sdpData = "v=0\n" + 
                "o=user1 392867480 292042336 IN IP4 192.168.10.31\n" + 
                "s=-\n" + 
                "c=IN IP4 192.168.10.31\n" + 
                "t=0 0\n" + 
                "m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\n" + 
                "a=sendrecv";
         byte[] contents = sdpData.getBytes();
        // this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory
        // .createContactHeader(contactAddress);

        request = this.messageFactory.createRequest("sip:"+this.toPrefix+this.toNumber+'@'
                + this.toUri + " SIP/2.0\r\n\r\n");
        request.addHeader(viaHeader);
        request.addHeader(maxForwardsHeader);
        request.addHeader(toHeader);
        request.addHeader(fromHeader);
        request.addHeader(callIdHeader);
        request.addHeader(cSeqHeader);
        request.addHeader(contactHeader);
        request.addHeader(contentLength);
        request.addHeader(contentType);
        if (response != null) {
                            retry = true;
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Response: "+response);
        }
        inviteTid = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);
        // send the request out.
        inviteTid.sendRequest();
        this.dialog = inviteTid.getDialog();
        // Send the request statelessly through the SIP provider.
        // this.sipProvider.sendRequest(request);

        // Display the message in the text area.
        logger.debug("Request sent:\n" + request.toString() + "\n\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If an error occurred, display the error.
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.debug("Request sent failed: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
}
```

And this is the processResponse:

```
@Override
public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) {
    System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse());
    int statusCode = responseEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode > 400 && statusCode < 410) {
    if(statusCode == 401 && current_process.contains("REGISTER")) {
        register(responseEvent.getResponse());
    }
    else if(statusCode == 401 && current_process.contains("INVITE")) {
        System.out.println("Invite 401");
    }
    else if(statusCode == 200) {
        System.out.println("Registered");
        call(null);
    }       
    else {
        System.out.println("Other code: "+ statusCode);
    }
}
```

I have successfully registered the account to the server, but when it began the INVITE request, there is no response returned.

Below is the response I got (including the REGISTER responses), in the end you will see that my outgoing INVITE request doesn't return any responses.

```
DEBUG - Request sent:
REGISTER sip:sip.dialnow.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.31:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-343133-c591d8f797a179ed25a2114311df1854
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>
From: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>;tag=706572717
Call-ID: 6e49a1b2631c4b107199a8b7d9c5ee52@192.168.10.31
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:Frax01@192.168.10.31:5060;transport=UDP>
Expires: 120
Content-Length: 0




SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.31:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-343133-c591d8f797a179ed25a2114311df1854
From: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>;tag=706572717
To: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>
Contact: <sip:77.72.169.129:5060>
Call-ID: 6e49a1b2631c4b107199a8b7d9c5ee52@192.168.10.31
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: (Very nice Sip Registrar/Proxy Server)
Allow: ACK,BYE,CANCEL,INVITE,REGISTER,OPTIONS,INFO,MESSAGE
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="sip.dialnow.com",nonce="2849852658",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 0


12d2ad0d764601c0573be88a3d94a2d8
8b3a241c08615fba24fb161a2a344cc9
40810f9cf3d19138dc0875dea15e3970
DEBUG - Request sent:
REGISTER sip:sip.dialnow.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.31:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-343133-3ccb8a78b8614638665f0af2a998a686
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>
From: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>;tag=706572717
Call-ID: 50baef7c3a407e50d4d539a1e35cff41@192.168.10.31
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:Frax01@192.168.10.31:5060;transport=UDP>
Expires: 120
Authorization: Digest realm="sip.dialnow.com",nonce="2849852658",username="Frax01",uri="sip:sip.dialnow.com",algorithm=MD5,response="40810f9cf3d19138dc0875dea15e3970"
Content-Length: 0




SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.31:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-343133-3ccb8a78b8614638665f0af2a998a686
From: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>;tag=706572717
To: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>
Contact: <sip:77.72.169.129:5060>
Call-ID: 50baef7c3a407e50d4d539a1e35cff41@192.168.10.31
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Server: (Very nice Sip Registrar/Proxy Server)
Allow: ACK,BYE,CANCEL,INVITE,REGISTER,OPTIONS,INFO,MESSAGE
Content-Length: 0


Other code: 100
SIP/2.0 200 Ok
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.31:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-343133-3ccb8a78b8614638665f0af2a998a686
From: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>;tag=706572717
To: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>
Contact: <sip:Frax01@192.168.10.31:5060;transport=udp>;expires=120
Call-ID: 50baef7c3a407e50d4d539a1e35cff41@192.168.10.31
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Server: (Very nice Sip Registrar/Proxy Server)
Allow: ACK,BYE,CANCEL,INVITE,REGISTER,OPTIONS,INFO,MESSAGE
Content-Length: 0


Registered
DEBUG - Request sent:
INVITE sip:6281386725319@dialnow.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.31:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-343133-e18f3eca8f76bd0a4378a12dd6e7a0d7
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:6281386725319@dialnow.com>
From: <sip:Frax01@sip.dialnow.com>;tag=706572717
Call-ID: 66341e5e43e50e106a7fbf2866c0a1d3@192.168.10.31
CSeq: 3 INVITE
Contact: <sip:Frax01@192.168.10.31:5060;transport=UDP>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 300
```

As you can see it just stopped after the INVITE request is sent.

Thank you in advance,

Adam.

---

Further information:

I have tried user2932861's suggestions to no luck. I have tried using my public IP address but it's still stuck at the INVITE request. Also, I have set my SDP content, below is my SDP content:

```
        ContentTypeHeader contentType = this.headerFactory.createContentTypeHeader("application", "sdp");

        String sdpData = "v=0\n" + 
                "o=user1 392867480 292042336 IN IP4 *my IP*\n" + 
                "s=-\n" + 
                "c=IN IP4 *my IP*\n" + 
                "t=0 0\n" + 
                "m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\n" + 
                "a=sendrecv";
         byte[] contents = sdpData.getBytes();

         request.setContent(contents, contentType);
```

Note: the IP address is censored.

Thank you in advance!

---

As a matter of fact, it didn't exactly return NO responses at all, after a while being silent (not returning anything), the console would show "transaction timeout." Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

transaction timeout corresponds to sip timeout which should be 32s. You get this 408 answer because you received no answer. This is an automated answer generated by the stack itself, not an answer by a remote party.

Did you check your firewall settings? If you have no problem with your OS firewall, did you check your home gateway?

Are REGISTER and INVITE requests sent to the same ip address? you can check using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

yohann

Comment: Hey Yohann! Thanks for replying. Is it possible that the firewall's blocking something, even though the REGISTER requests are successful? Any rough idea what I should look for in the firewall settings? 
Is there any alternative to wireshark for Linux? Wireshark doesn't provide Linux version of the program, sadly. Thank you again, Yohann! Appreciate it. Edit: There IS wireshark for Linux, how stupid of me. I'll check the IP the requests send to and report back to you.

Comment: For firewall issue, I agree. But you should check that REGISTER and INVITE requests are sent to the same real ip address. Wireshark is available for linux. You can also use tcpdump if you like old tools, but wireshark is more user friendly.

Comment: you should use your linux distribution package manager to install new software. Search on internet for more details on this.

Comment: I have checked with Wireshark, and they do not send to the same IP address, for some reason. Any idea why they're doing this? Which parameter do I have to change to correctly send the requests to the IP?

Comment: maybe you should try to call sip:6281386725319@sip.dialnow.com instead of sip:6281386725319@dialnow.com

Comment: #RESPECT, it worked. It now returns 401, so I'll have to do ACK and reinvite, right? Thank you, Yohann!

Comment: not reinvite, but invite with credentials (challenge management). You need to add Authorization header with appropriate value but I think jain-sip already has what's necessary to manage authentication.

Answer (score 0):

My guess for your woes:

Your contact headers are showing private addresses. Try using publicly routable addresses here. ( You can use STUN to discover your public address or some other means.) If you are going through a B2BUA (AKA session border controller), it would rewrite those for you. Firewall and NAT traversal in SIP is non trivial.

Also, you have a content length in your INVITE but do you have content? Did you forget to set your SDP content?

Comment: I have edited my main post in response to your answer, please take a look! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with low level SIP, why don't you try a higher level framework such as SIP Servlets https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/ which let you focus on your core business logic ? You can even try an Amazon AMI https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00G9G94JW/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-3&qid=1383128640630#support